# GET request for person returns both person and company in xml format

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So if I had a PersonController and a CompanyController and I call www.example.com/api/person?id=34 it will return both person and company embed into the person xml like so:

```
<Person xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Example.Models">
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <PersonId>34</PersonId>
    <Company>
             <Name>Blah</Name>
    </Company>
</Person>
```

How would this be done in mvc 4 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added this to the code to format the xml the way I wanted to this is person

```
public string PersonId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public Company company { get; set; }
```

this is company:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

This is my controller

```
cinfo = new Company[] {new Company {Name = CompanyName}};
info.Add(new Person {PersonId = PersonID, Name = PersonName, company = cinfo[0]});
```

This is all shortened but these are the changes